# Удалить токен из localStorage каждый полчаса

Tags: reactjs, localstorage, token

подскажите пожалуйста как можно обновить токен автоматически каждый полчаса, как написать функцию на Javascript. Дело в том, что для проекта, над которым работаю написан Api для авторизации, и Api каждый полчаса обновляет токен, я этот токен храню в localStorage, и надо сделать так, чтобы старый токен удалился автоматически каждый полчаса. Пожалуйста подскажите, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за внимание, дорогие друзья.
Нашел ответ
Функция для сохранения токена в sessionStorage

```js
function saveToken(token) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('tokenData', JSON.stringify(token));
}
```

Функция для получения токена:

```js
function getTokenData(login, password) {
    return fetch('api/auth', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            login,
            password,
        }),
    })
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                const tokenData = res.json();
                saveToken(JSON.stringify(tokenData)); // сохраняем полученный токен в sessionStorage, с помощью функции, заданной ранее
                return Promise.resolve()
            }
            return Promise.reject();
        });
}
```

Обновление токена:

```js
function refreshToken(token) {
    return fetch('api/auth/refreshToken', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            token,
        }),
    })
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                const tokenData = res.json();
                saveToken(JSON.stringify(tokenData)); // сохраняем полученный обновленный токен в sessionStorage, с помощью функции, заданной ранее
                return Promise.resolve();
            }
            return Promise.reject();
        });
}
```

Функция-обертка:

```js
export async function fetchWithAuth(url, options) {
    
    const loginUrl = '/login'; // url страницы для авторизации
    let tokenData = null; // объявляем локальную переменную tokenData

    if (sessionStorage.authToken) { // если в sessionStorage присутствует tokenData, то берем её
        tokenData = JSON.parse(localStorage.tokenData);
    } else {
       return window.location.replace(loginUrl); // если токен отсутствует, то перенаправляем пользователя на страницу авторизации
    }

    if (!options.headers) { // если в запросе отсутствует headers, то задаем их
        options.headers = {};
    }
    
    if (tokenData) {
        if (Date.now() >= tokenData.expires_on * 1000) { // проверяем не истек ли срок жизни токена
            try {
                const newToken = await refreshToken(tokenData.refresh_token); // если истек, то обновляем токен с помощью refresh_token
                saveToken(newToken);
            } catch () { // если тут что-то пошло не так, то перенаправляем пользователя на страницу авторизации
               return  window.location.replace(loginUrl);
            }
        }

        options.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${tokenData.token}`; // добавляем токен в headers запроса
    }

    return fetch(url, options); // возвращаем изначальную функцию, но уже с валидным токеном в headers
}
```

Я вот в этой статье нашел ответ, кому интересно можете посмотреть
https://habr.com/ru/post/456188/

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/418391)

Comment: Да, вы правы, Спасибо Вам, исправил